# Angular not updating view on updates

Tags: javascript, angular, browser, rxjs, pipe

I have a service where I'm listening to browser print events.

```
@Injectable()
export class ApplicationSession {
  printStream$: Observable<boolean>;

  constructor() {
    this._setupPrintListener();
  }

  private _setupPrintListener(): void {
    if (this._window.matchMedia) {
      const beforePrintEvent = fromEvent(this._window, 'beforeprint')
        .pipe(mapTo(true));
      const afterPrintEvent = fromEvent(this._window, 'afterprint')
        .pipe(mapTo(false));

      this.printStream$ = merge(beforePrintEvent, afterPrintEvent).pipe(startWith(false));
    }
  }
}
```

Then, in my Component, I'm binding property to the `printStream$` property of the service instance. As in,

```
export class ReferralComponent {
  printRequested$: Observable<boolean>;

  constructor(session: ApplicationSession) {
    this.printRequested$ = session.printStream$;
    //Observing values here
    this.printRequested$.subscribe(console.log);
  }
}
```

I use the component's `printRequested$` property to create and destroy an angular component asynchronously.

```
<generic-angular-component *ngIf="printRequested$ | async"></generic-angular-component>
```

I have a child component within the `ReferralComponent` that has a button which triggers `window.print()` function. As in,

```
@Component({
  template: `<button (click)="print()">Print</button>`
})
export class ChildComponent {
  print() {
    window.print();
  }
}
```

My problem is, when I press Command/Ctrl + P from the keyboard, I see angular creating and destroying the `<generic-angular-component>`. However, when I trigger the `window.print()` via the child component button click, I can see the `true/false` values being passed on the stream. However, Angular doesn't seem to care about it at all. I don't see the component at all.

Here's a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ky9qnd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) reproduction. 
You can either click on Print button and see that there's no *Toggle Me* line at the bottom left of the print preview page. Or, you can press Command/Ctrl + P and see that it (*Toggle Me*) is there at the bottom left.

Comment: Just for comparison:  have you tried to use an RXJS subject to signal from the child component to the main component which has an observable to listen to the event (which in turn would launch a windows print command)?  just to see if you can trigger printStream$ observable as with the control-P

Comment: @jcuypers I tried doing that. But I ended up abandoning the idea once I ended up writing this.printRequested$ = of(true) in the event change handler function.

Comment: It seems to be a common 'problem'...  . it comes down to the fact that 'ctrl-P' behavior != window.print behavior. I found a lot of issues through google.  you might want to check this.

Comment: You helped me out in abandoning this idea. I think I'm gonna propose the team to find another solution. From my understanding, browsers print what they see currently in the DOM. So, we found a hack-y way to render a printer friendly component before printing and destroying it after print. However, this doesn't seem to work in Safari (in Command + P) event and Safari was only the second browser I tested this code on after Chrome. I can only imagine the pain in other older browsers. This seems like the wrong way to go to solve this issue.

Comment: I don't know exactly your requirements, but there are some quite extensive solutions alreay available for printing.  you might want to check those.

Comment: Yeah, I think just a "Show me a printer friendly version of this page" button would be suffice in our scenario. Just need to get everyone to agree on that. Original idea seemed liked the easiest option when it was proposed.